# Is there a way to convert ipa to xcode file?

Tags: ios, xcode

My computer got damaged. I lost my xcode project files. But I have the ipa file for the app. Is there a way to convert the ipa file to xcode? or to at lease recover some of the project files by using the ipa file?

Comment: Sorry about that, but you can't turn the hamburger back into the steak.

Comment: No, there isn't. Were you not using version control (remote server) or a time-machine backup?

Comment: Nope, out of luck! @Abizern, you mean turn it back into the cow? Who turns steak into a burger???

Comment: Not all steaks are created equal.

Comment: Please use source code control and Time Machine. There is no need to suffer loses like this. It is a shame that so many people don't bother with backups until it's too late.

Comment: Remember 3-2-1: 3(at least) copies of important files. On 2 different media and 1 copy offsite.

Comment: @Abizern I have never heard that saying before when it comes to backing up but it seems like something I should be living by :-). `SusanJackie` I feel your pain I really do all that hard work lost. Learn from this experience get some sort of source control set up `SVN`, `GIT` etc and don't have it set up on your local machine have it set up on a server(s), external harddrive(s) and have backups of your backups. Good luck on getting everything setup again.

Comment: You know, CDR disks are pretty cheap, and virtually every computer sold in the last ten years can write them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is not. You code is compiled to native code. So unless you are really good at reading assembly you are really out of luck.

You will be able to extract the resources from the ipa (it's just an zip file).

Answer (score 0):

NO!! if it would have been possible then anyone could have downloaded multiple apps and then via tools like iExplorer explored the apps to devices and turned it back to the code and hence no security!

Comment: Actually there are some app which are just copies of some other app in the AppStore. Were they copied an IPA, changed some resources and resigned the app and uploaded it to the AppStore again.

Comment: No, they can't submit the same app again by just changing the resources. First, they are read only, and secondly ipa is compiled from a provision profile and for sure apple will always check the app bundle identifier against the app submission in it's pre submission check list. Also, there are companies who build same kind of apps, they try to modify images + concept of the app and rest backend, UI flow stays the same..

Comment: Yes they can and have, looking for the blog post by a developer hose app got stollen right now.

Comment: I would love to see the same, can you share the link. Thanks.

Comment: Here is the blog post: http://lipsky.me/blog/2013/7/2/pirated-apps-in-the-app-store